# Adding adobe elements based on selection

Tags: pdf, pdf-form

I havent work with adobe for a long time. Trying to make an interactive form that would work in Adobe DC Pro. I have a bunch of repeated elements but not nescessary used all the time. Can I make programmatically to create automatically rows if I need more as example:

| Date | Name | Department | Quantitty | +

So I press plus to add new fields rows in the pdf form

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Propaganda used to say to use XFA (aka LiveCycle Designer, nowadays a paying component of the Experience Cloud (I think)).

However, it is possible to do this programmatically, using Acrobat JavaScript.

If the area is given, and the number of lines is limited, you can do it with simple show/hide commands.

If you a non-limited number of items, you'd have to do a bit more planning, and use the addField() and related command to create your fields, maybe in connection with Template pages (see Acrobat JavaScript documentation for that). In my experience, it helps a lot if you can separate data entry and display, while keeping the data in an array. This makes managing entries much easier. As you state that it is for Acrobat Pro (and not Reader), you won't have any Adobe-inflicted restrictions.

I have been doing such tables routinely for almost two decades, and it is not that difficult; as said, have a good look at the documentation. If you happen to consider buying over making, feel free to contact me in private.